# Software Updater error

Tags: update-manager, locale

I am having serious trouble with setting up the ethernet connection in Ubuntu 16.04, so I thought of doing a software update and did so. It stopped halfway through with this black screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0R0z.png

```
perl: warning: setting locale failed. 
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: 
        LANGUAGE = (unset), 
        LC ALL = (unset), 
        LANG = "en IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system. 
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory  
locale: Cannot set LC CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 1 :
I followed what Ken Sharp said in the comment section :
Does this look right now ?

```
$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
$
```

Comment: There does not exist any `"en IN.ISO8859-1"` locale in Ubuntu. You need to change `LANG` to a value which does exist and has been generated on your system.

Comment: you just need to set a real locale, check out this guide: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson does it look right now ?

Comment: Yes it does! :)